# Swift 3 How to reference to row index in UITableViewRowAction

Tags: swift, indexing, tableview

So I am trying to create a custom swipe in table view including a delete and an edit button. However, I cannot reference to the row of the selected cell that i want to edit. The index in this case come out to be [x, y], with x always being 0, referring to the index of the edit button when swiped, while y is the row index.

How can I reference to the row index, in other words, y in [x, y]. Thanks!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        self.leaveLeaveType.remove(at: index.row)
        self.leaveStartsTime.remove(at: index.row)
        self.leaveEndsTime.remove(at: index.row)
        self.leaveHost.remove(at: index.row)
        self.leaveDest.remove(at: index.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [index], with: .fade)
    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editLeaveRequest", sender: self)
        let editCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index)! as! LeaveRequestTableViewCell
        self.editLeaveType = editCell.leaveLeaveType.text!
        self.editHost = editCell.leaveHost.text!
        self.editDest = editCell.leaveDest.text!

        let cellDateTime = editCell.leaveDateTime.text!
        let startsTimeStartIndex = cellDateTime.index(cellDateTime.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
        let startsTimeEndIndex = cellDateTime.index(cellDateTime.endIndex, offsetBy: -22)
        let startsTimeRange = startsTimeStartIndex..<startsTimeEndIndex
        self.editStartsTime = cellDateTime[startsTimeRange]

        let endsTimeStartIndex = cellDateTime.index(cellDateTime.startIndex, offsetBy: 22)
        let endsTimeEndIndex = cellDateTime.index(cellDateTime.endIndex, offsetBy: 0)
        let endsTimeRange = endsTimeStartIndex..<endsTimeEndIndex
        self.editEndsTime = cellDateTime[endsTimeRange]

    }

    delete.backgroundColor = .red
    edit.backgroundColor = .lightGray

    return [delete, edit]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code cannot work because the local parameter label `indexPath` is missing

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
      editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {...
```

This `indexPath` contains the section and row of the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help...but when I swipe and try to print the indexPath, it is still showing sth like [x, y], such as [0,0] or [0,1], the 0, 1 are the rows. Also, since I have a delete and an edit button, I found that they both result in the same [x, y] when pressed, then what does the x in [x, y] index stand for?

Comment: But i cant seem to do let editCell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: [indexPath.row])! as! LeaveRequestTableViewCell

Comment: No, `cellForRow...` expects the *full* index path: `cellForRow(at: indexPath)` The index path is captured in the closure.

Comment: ok, i get it. however, when i do click edit, and segues into a new controller, the index path is still wrong.